# using php + javascript to change image from select

Tags: php, javascript, html

Basically, I am doing this: I have already read the database and obtained all the items, each includes a 'name' and a 'link'. On the page, I have an image, a select menu, and a button; each select option displays an item name (but no link information). I want to implement this: first select an option (nothing happen), and then click the button to change the image src to the selected item's link (in PHP variable). But I have trouble to pass the link to the javascript function, because it involves PHP variable. The code is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectItem(i) {
var name, link;
/*
...
*/
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;
document.getElementById("pic").src = link;
}
</script>
...
<body>
<img id="pic" src="default.png">
<div id="name"></div>
<div onclick="location.href='javascript:selectItem(document.
    getElementsByName(&quot;menu&quot;)[0].value)';"></div>
<select name="menu">
    <option value="">select one</option>
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($items as $item):
        echo ("<option value=\"" . $i . "\">" . $item['name'] . "</option>");
        $i++;
    endforeach;
    ?>
</select>
</body>
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is late, but my solution is: to record name and link together (separated by " | ") in the attribute "value" of each option. Then there is no need to pass PHP variable to the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Is the foreach loop actually looping? Try:

```
 <?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) { ?>
    <option value="<? echo $i ?>"><? echo $item['name'] ?></option>
<?  $i++; }
?>
```

Comment: it is. But the problem is, I could only record the name here, not both name and link.

Comment: So you want the image to change after selecting the name of a different image and clicking the button? Where is your button? Are you using that div? Is there a reason you don't want to add the button to your form instead?